# Call same function from two different threads

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a function:

```
- (void)fetchClassListOnCompletion:(void(^) (BOOL success, NSArray *classlist))completionBlock;
```

I want to call this function from two different thread (may be simultaneously) and want the classlist from the one that finished last.

Need help to implement this

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    [self fetchClassListOnCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSArray *classlist) {
         self.classList = classlist;
    }];
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    [self fetchClassListOnCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSArray *classlist) {
         self.classList = classlist;
    }];
});
```

`self.classList` will be assigned to `classlist` from the block that finishes last.

Because this runs on background thread, make sure your method doesn't need to be run on main thread.